# SQL result to "normalized" XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have been tasked with exporting SQL data to XML. I have to pull all of the people who worked on each file along with their email address, union them all together and assign them an id. I just used the row number to set as their ID - it does not matter if they change, they just have to be consistent when we are uploading this XML file.

With those `addressid`s, we have to replace the responsible party in each file with the respective IDs.

The end result would look something like this:

```
<Addresses>
    <Address Name="SomeName" Email= "SomeEmail" Addressid="SomeID"/>
</Addresses>
<Files>
    <File party1id="2" Party2ID="3" Party3ID="6" />
</Files>
```

I have the Address table working, but I'm having difficulty pulling out all of the IDs for each party. Joining on that table multiple times is not a viable solution.

Does anyone have a better way on how to go about this?

Comment: Please provide sample data of your tables also -HTH ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
;with t as (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by Addressid order by partyId) rn
    from party
)
select (
    select 
        [Name] 'Address/@Name',
        Email 'Address/@Email',
        Addressid 'Address/@Addressid'
    from Addresses
    for xml path('Addresses')) + 
    '<Files><File ' + replace((
    select 'Party'+cast(rn as varchar(5))+'ID='''+cast(partyId as varchar(5))+''' '
    from t
    where Addresses.Addressid = t.Addressid
    for xml path('')
    ),'''', '"') + '/></Files>'
from Addresses;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8516)
or

```
select 
    [Name] 'Addresses/Addresse/@Name',
    Email 'Addresses/Addresse/@Email',
    Addressid 'Addresses/Addresse/@Addressid',
    party1id 'Files/File/@party1id',
    Party2ID 'Files/File/@Party2ID',
    Party3ID 'Files/File/@Party3ID'
from 
    t
for xml path('');
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8513)